# SP2010: How to click a button automatically upon selection of an option in a choice column

Tags: 2010, list-form, choice-field

I've a choice field in a list form where multiple selection is enabled. I want to click a button (a custom one I've added) on selection of some options. How can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Korak

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this purpose.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#idoftheTableElementContainer input").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            //label next to checkbox holds the value. 
            if ($(this).next().val() == "random value") {
                $("#idofbutton").click();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure JQuery is referenced to the page.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm not sure if I'm entering the correct id for the checkbox. It looks like 
ctl00_m_g_a186c028_a2e3_485b_8545_63786566994a_ctl00_ListFieldIterator2_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00

Comment: Multiselect choice columns is rendered as a many check boxes inside a <table>. You have to get the id of the <table> element